# How to show child form in desire location of MDI form?

Tags: windows, winforms, mdi

I have two Groupbox on MDI and location of them are top and left so my right side part is blank. Now I want to show child form there.

Please let me know how can I display child form without setting doc=fill.I want to show statusbar so need to have child form on top of that.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You can't place groupbox controls on an MDI form.

Comment: You can, the control *has* to be docked to an edge.  Same for a status strip, dock it to the bottom.  Nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use splitter control; on the left side put the combo boxes, on the right - mdi container.